# Pyspark GroupBy and count too slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running pyspark on dataproc cluster with 4 nodes, each node having 2 cores and 8 GB RAM.
I have a dataframe with a column containing list of words. I exploded this column and counted the number of occurences using-

```
df.groupBy("exploded_col").count()
```

Before exploding, there were ~78 mn rows.
But, running the above code takes too long (more than 4 hours). Why is spark taking unusually long time? I'm still new to spark, so I'm not fully aware of appropriate settings to deal with huge data.

I have the following settings for sparkContext

```
enter code here
SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Spark NLP Licensed") \
    .master("yarn") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.1") 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",20)
spark.conf.set("spark.num.executors",100)
spark.conf.set("spark.executor.cores",1)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
```

I even set "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"  to 2001, but that didn't work either.
Please help.

Comment: I think the problem comes because the data is not distributed properly. When you run the group by clause, if data is present randomly on all nodes, there will be a lot of shuffling, which I believe is the problem you are facing. Can you see that on the Spark UI? Try going to the stages and see how much shuffling is there on the nodes

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the poor performance is that groupBy usually cause a data shuffle between the executors. You can use the built in spark function `countDistinct` in this manner:

```
from spark.sql.functions import countDistinct
df.agg(countDistinct("exploded_col"))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried countDistinct(), but it's also taking a long time.

Comment: What is the size of your data? what is the size and configuration of the cluster?

Comment: On dataproc UI, pending Yarn memory goes upto 2.9 TB. There are 4 nodes in the cluster each of n1-standard2 type.

Comment: Then it probably mean that the cluster is too small for handling the data. Which format is it? If it comes from BigQuery, Parquet or similar you can load just the relevant column which should reduce (depends on the schema) the size of the data. If it doesn't help, please increase the cluster size

Comment: It is loaded from .orc format, I am working with just 3 columns. Btw, I performed count() and it gave quick result. I can't increase the cluster size, so is there any changes in spark config (that I have shared in the ques.)  that would improve the processing?

Comment: Count works much quicker as it usually don't load any data, just scan it. have you tried `df.select("exploded_col").distinct().count()` ?

Comment: I tried distinct().count() , but it is taking long time as well. Is there any configuration setting that needs to be tweaked?